Two files with clear differences wont merge, and only gives 'Already up to date' message
I have a strange issue that I do not understand. I have branch A and branch B, both of them clearly differ, but when I merge B into A nothing happens, or git tells me that I'm already up to date. I can however merge A into B.
I did a small test where i did a small commit in B and then merged B to A, the small change i did got merged into A but non of the other lines of code that differ. It is almost like A think it is equal to B but in practice not. Running git diff will however show that they do differ, so it not like git does not know about the differences.
* 54272bb (HEAD) started created the controller for poweroffice go
| *   1d5286f (origin/copyNorwayMatsWorkingBranch, copyNorwayMatsWorkingBranch) Merged PR 3328: test
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | 8896671 (origin/NorwayWorkingBranch, NorwayWorkingBranch) test
| * 200ca79 (NorwayMatsWorkingBranch) commite
| *   6ea8307 (origin/add-new-keyvault-factory, origin/NorwayMatsWorkingBranch, add-new-keyvault-factory) COmmit
| |\
| | *   7f42752 (origin/NSEBranch) Merged PR 2549: keyvault factory PR
| | |\
| | | *   e5c7c13 Fixed COnflicts
| | | |\
| | | |/
| | |/|
| * | | 2d8c844 Pushing merge


How do they differ? May you share the commit tree? Please share the git commands you've used and their output

What you describe hints at that B is an ancester of A. Perhaps it has been merged into A earlier. BTW, to merge branches does not mean that they then have the same content and that there will be no differences.

Yes they have been merged before. I cant share the commit tree unfortunately. The commands i do are the basic ones, checkout, merge push pull

Is there a rule saying that one can only merge once ? or

Please forgive me if this sounds rude, but do you know what a merge is/does?

im very new to git so probably not hehe. But what i thought was that if i merge B into A then the changes for B will be applied to A (assuming no conflicts)

I like to think that you add the commits from B to A (but that is more like rebase i guess)

Please may you update the question with the output of git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph?

From that output, may you tell us which is A and which is B?

did it now, cant show all though as the size is huge

So I want to merge NorwayWorkingBranch into copyNorwayMatsWorkingBranch. I have however testet it with a bunch of branches just to test. So the branch history may seem a bit messy with alot of bad commits

@Mats-JohanFagerheim it's already merged. There's nothing new to merge. Perhaps you can explain what outcome you are trying to achieve, that you don't currently have, and we can help you with that. But merging again is obviously not the solution.

Well i guess it makes sense. If i Merge a branch A with B and then do some changes in B, merging again would not change my code (assuming A has no new commits) as all commits are part of the branch. In my case this surprised me as there where some code lines i did not touch in my branch at all that still did not get change in the merge, but this is probably one of does cases where I have done something that i dont recall.

This is normal and expected behavior when "B is an ancestor of A". This could be because you have already merged B into A, or, A branched off of B in the past. Since there are no commits on B that aren't already in the history of A, there is nothing to merge.
Note that being an ancestor of another commit has nothing to do with the current states of those commits, which is why git diff A B has differences.
If you run the command git log A you'll see that the tip of B shows up in the log somewhere.

Is there a way to force it? It is okey if i get alot of conflicts i can manually fix them

@Mats-JohanFagerheim You can't force it to merge again if there's nothing to merge.
